# Thickness of a drawn line changes when the UIView resizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView which resizes itself according to the pinch gesture. I also have two lines drawn in the drawrect of the above view. I noticed that the thickness of the line changes when the view resizes. Any idea why?

code in my controller class

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
        recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
        recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

code inside the UIView subclass

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"Drawing code");
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 20.0f, 5.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 20.0f, rect.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);

    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 0.0f, rect.size.height - 20);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, rect.size.width - 20, rect.size.height - 20);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
```

After reading the answers and suggestions I tried the following,

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
        recognizer.view.frame = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(recognizer.view.frame, CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale));
}
```

But it gave me the following error,

[image]

Comment: It's because you are changing the view.transform. Try changing the view frame in handlePinch:, instead, and then calling the [view needsLayout] method.

Answer (score 0):

A transform will transform the entire view including what is drawn in it. Instead, change the size of the view and redraw it. Something like:

```
myView.frame = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(myView.frame, inverseAffine);
```

Scale may need to be considered as well.

Comment: Can you suggest a code which could change the size according to the scale given by the UIPinchGestureRecognizer?

Comment: Updating answer with a partial solution, although you'll need to do some legwork

Comment: how to get the inverseAffine value?

Comment: That was from copy/paste. You need to use your transform from the pinch.

Comment: You already did in your code above. See the parts where you create a transform: `CGAffineTransformScale`